# Unable to find cause why Joomla website blacklisted by Google (Deceptive site ahead)

Tags: google-search-console, security, joomla, malware, block

We developed a new website for our company. 
The old website work on Joomla 2.5, for example **https**://www.company.com.
Page www.company.com/administrator closed by password via .htaccess

The new website we developed on Joomla 3.9, placed it on a temporary separate domain, for example **http**://www.test.com.
This website disallowed for indexing by robots.txt.
Page www.test.com/administrator is available without a password .htaccess.
Https version is available only via self-signed certificate.
The new website is radically different design.

After a month of development, when the website is almost ready there was a problem.
Website www.test.com has been blocked by Google Safe Browsing.
[image: Warning - Deceptive site ahead]
The website is blocked in Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Google Search Console Screenshots :
[image: Search Console 1]
[image: Search Console 2]

I checked the page www.test.com/administrator for viruses 
[image: scan - sucuri]
I compared the files with standard files of Joomla. There is no difference, all files is okey.
Didn't find anything suspicious.

I checked on virustotal
[image: scan - virustotal]

I can't find the true cause.

- The message in the browser: Deceptive website ahead
- The message in Google Search Console: Harmful content
- The message in Virustotal (Google Safebrowsing): Phishing

I am afraid to upload the new website to the main domain.

Can the new website be blacklisted on the primary domain?

How to determine the exact cause for blocking?

Is the default page for Joomla /administrator has security problems, and google blocks the whole website?

Answer (score 2):

If the new website has been developed independently from the infected website then you may be able to delete the files on the server and the database and then upload the new website cleanly without infection.

If the new website has occupied the same hosting account then it is likely also infected.

You can use a commercial service such as https://sucuri.net or https://myjoomla.com to find and remove the malware. Reinstalling all extensions over the top of the existing extensions can help too.

Once you are confident the malware has been removed, you'll need to contact Google via Search Console to notify them that the website has been cleaned.

For more details see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/2339/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/180/120

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. But my problem is definitely not viruses or hacking. My site is not hacked or infected with a virus. This is definitely checked by a lot of anti-viruses. As I wrote above: I can't find the true cause. Google does not report this cause. As I find out, the message "Deceptive site ahead" Google may imply any reason. Now I suspect some features of http and https for Google.

Comment: Many free malware detection tools will report the website is OK because they don't have full access to your website. To properly check for malware, use a paid tool like Sucuri or myJoomla or try copying the website to your local machine and use an up to date virus scanner on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You say, new website is placed it on a temporary separate domain. There is a clear cause on the test page: "domain is blacklisted by Google Safe Browsing".

Beside of this, what means "new website we developed on Joomla 3.9". What exactly do you developed? Template? Extensions? Hacked in the core?

I would say, make on the clean domain a clean Joomla install, upload your template and extensions after virustotal check, and you are on secure side.

Comment: Evgeniy, thank you very much for your reply.
We have developed a new template, set up several reliable paid extensions, filled the site with new content.
I understand that I can check everything on a new clean domain, but if the problem is repeated the same way, then I also will not see the true cause.
Can I find out the true cause now?
By cause I mean Phishing, Malware or self-signed SSL certificate.
And why in Search Console I see a problem only on the page "www.test.com/administrator"? Could it be in the case of Phishing? Or Google really see "Harmful content" on this page? Thank you.

Comment: You don't know the history of the domain, where you host you stage - its history contains the answer to your question. Everything you see in the search console and SERP is caused by blacklisting. In general i don't understand why use blacklisted domain for stage. Why don't use a subdomain on domain, which is definitely clean and good...?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but this cannot be the true cause. Domain "test.com" I have more than 5 years and it has never been used. It was always parked. Now I suspect some features of http and https for Google.